# Equal height rows with items need to be pushed to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap having 3 columns.

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

Using [this link](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) (just css I added above) I was able to get columns with equal heights. But in the smaller height column, I have 3 rows. Top 2 are not rows, they are just div.

Bottom one is a `class="row"` because its contents are two columns with `class='col-lg-6'`. Now I want this "row" (mentioned above) to be pushed to bottom of that page which is not happening.  I tried moving it to bottom by adding position:absolute to this "row" but that distorted this row feature(I mean distorted the way `col-lg-6` works). Whats solution ?

Here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/lareholula/edit?html). Please see in full screen.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: That doesn't demonstrate the problem, we need a demo of the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks for enouraging Pauli. Here is the link http://jsbin.com/lareholula/edit?html